# Female anime character with powers and an amulet on her chest

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for this anime/TV show from jetix or fox kids that I really liked but never got to actually watch as a kid. I only saw a few episodes so I don't know the whole plot. It involved a girl with some sort of amulet/stone above her chest. Or was it her forehead??!! Anyway, she was mostly unconscious but always ended up saving the day with her powers, at which point the amulet started to glow and change colors. There was also a boy who had to drag the girl along while they where travelling somewhere. I only remember some scenes with waterfalls and stuff which don't really help. But I do recall that the girl was white, had long dark hair, with perhaps white or pale blue clothing, and that the show probably aired somewhere around 2001 to 2005. It was a Japanese-style fantasy and adventure anime and the characters seemed around 13 to 16. I know it's really vague but any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: My first thought is *Nadia of the Blue Waters*, but she's definitely not unconscious most of the time.

Comment: Sound like magical girl type animation like `Winx`

Comment: How about Blue Seed ? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111897/ (there has been a sequel to it in 1997) Or on second thought, this is not set in a fantasy/adventure world.

Comment: I'm also thinking of the dark-haired version of El-Hazard's Ifurita, in the "Wanderers" timeline.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm not sure but Elemental Gelade and Eureka Seven somehow fits your description. The amulet/stone was located on female protagonist forehead though.